# How common are orange cats?

Tags: cats

Humans with red hair are about 1-2% of the population according to a quick Google search, but I seem to not be able to find anything about cats. I have an awesome orange tabby, and I'm curious how common is an orange cat vs. other cat colors?

Comment: Is [this cat](https://imgur.com/5Em0QLM) orange for you? If it is, then it is way more common than red headed humans.

Comment: here is a bit of reading for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_coat_genetics

Comment: Love the bananas for scale! Yes, that's an orange cat imo.